# How to get current initial value of Angular form control using RxJs

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a situation where I need to listen to the value of the form control from a different component. the `valueChanges` does this just fine for any changes in the dropdown. However I get a `null` upon initialization in ngOnInit. Apparently the valueChanges does not get the initial value of the FormControl- only upon changing it. So how can I get both the initial value as well as any subsequent changes?

An example which works fine for any changes, but not for getting an initial value upon load. If this form control already has some initial value in it, this code won't get it

```
this.form1.controls['name'].valueChanges.subscribe(change => {
  console.log(change); // Value inside the input field as soon as it changes
});
```

Comment: Pass in the initial value as an `@Input()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`startWith()` RXJS operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith) and provide the initial value of the form control.

```
this.form1.controls.name.valueChanges
      .pipe(startWith(this.form1.controls.name.value))
      .subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kqler3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)